# Strings being emptied by capitalize! when user enters input with correct formatting

Tags: ruby

I am working through some exercises at the moment.

I have written the following code

```
print "What's your first name?"
first_name=gets.chomp.capitalize!
print "Last name"
last_name=gets.chomp.capitalize!
print "City"
city=gets.chomp.capitalize!
print "State(Caps)"
state=gets.chomp.upcase!
print "Your name is #{first_name} #{last_name} from #{city}, #{state}"
```

When I use incorrect formatting for input (eg. john or nEW yORK, the routine runs fine.

However, if everything entered = the correct output, ie. John or New York, the routine empties the corresponding string variable.

Is there a way to ignore the capitalize! method if the input is correctly formatted?

Comment: Did any of the solutions work out for you @dez82?

Answer (score 6):

Try `capitalize` instead of the one with the "!". The version with the bang returns nil when nothing is changed. Docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21).

Answer (score 1):

`capitalize!` returns a capitalized string if it's *not* capitalized, and `nil` if there's nothing to capitalize (i.e. before and after are the same). See [String#capitalize!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21). There are other methods like this for strings, like `gsub!`, that return `nil` if the in-place edit does nothing.

Just use `capitalize` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here is giving you the reason why you get `nil` and the solution but I see no explanations of the difference between the methods you're using.

Every function and method in Ruby returns a value and sometimes there are two versions of the same method. One version usually returns a new object without modifying the original while the other modifies the original and may (or may not) return the changed value.

The latter type is almost always suffixed by an `!`. So what your code is doing is:

- get input from the user and store it as a string
- create a new string, remove the `\n` and return it
- capitalize the new string and modify itself

So the last object created is modified if needed and not returned because there's no reason to return that. Just like there is a `capitalize!` method on Strings, there is also a `chomp!` method. Imagine if instead if there were no `\n` at the end of the string returned from `gets`. Then `chomp!` would return `nil` and `nil.capitalize` would throw an exception.

If you change your code to just use `capitalize` as everyone else rightly tells you to, the execution will look like this:

- get input from the user and store it as a string
- create a new string, remove the `\n` and return it
- create a new string, capitalize it and return it